# What is the syntax to assign multiple enum values to a property in F#?

Tags: f#, enums, servicestack

I am writing a ServiceStack webservice in F# and need to limit some of the features (removing SOAP support for instance).

In C# I am using the pipe operation to assign multiple Enums (ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Feature) to the EnableFeatures property like so:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig
{
    DebugMode = true, //Show StackTraces in responses in development
    EnableFeatures = Feature.Json | Feature.Xml | Feature.Html | Feature.Metadata | Feature.Jsv
});
```

However in F# you can't use pipe to accomplish this, and everything else I try is attempting to do function application to the enums.  How do I go about assigning multiple enums in this case?

Comment: You've already got an answer, but it's worth noting this is not a pipe operator, it's 'bitwise or'. F#'s bitwise or operator, as pointed out by Craig Stuntz, is `|||`.

Comment: I think it's `|||||||`...oh wait, no, only `|||`.

Comment: @botanist Good to see you here--there are some really smart F# folks hereabouts.  And there's me too.

Comment: @Daniel For your convenience: `let inline (|||||||) a b = a ||| b` :-)

Comment: @TomasPetricek: :-) Thanks. Is it possible to get something like this to work: `let inline flags<'T, 'U when 'T : enum<'U>> items = List.reduce (|||) items`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a triple pipe:

```
EnableFeatures = Feature.Json ||| Feature.Xml ||| Feature.Html ||| Feature.Metadata ||| Feature.Jsv
```

Comment: Thank you sir!  I figured I was missing something simple, and indeed I was.  [F# Bitwise Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469495.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

If you have a bunch of them you can save a few keystrokes with `reduce`:

```
List.reduce (|||) [Feature.Json; Feature.Xml; Feature.Html; Feature.Metadata]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create the value based on the construction of the underlying values:

```
EnabledFeatures = enum<Feature>(16); // or whatever the full flag value would be for Json + Xml + Html + Metadata, etc
```

Comment: You could, but that's why we have symbolic names for flags and bitwise combining operators in the first place - so we don't have to.